# Make Listview (item has weight property) Horizontally scrollable

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

`Horizontal Scrollview` can be used for listview to make it scroll both side.

But my listview item is:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView87" />
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView88" />
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView89" />
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView90" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What I want : Consider the first textview. In all the rows, I need that textview width as same. (Same for all textviews)

Is there anyway to do this. Please help me!!!

Comment: can you explain it properly?  Cause its working perfectly in my device.

Comment: @Ashish each row has 4 textviews. I need it to be scrolled horizontally if the text is lengthy. but in all row, that textview width should be same. Please check it with different length of texts. (it should look like an spread sheet)

Comment: @JyotiJK See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:weightSum="4"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/textView87" />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/textView88" />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/textView89" />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/textView90" />
```